# MongoDB Regex Query : Why doesn't this work?

Tags: regex, mongodb

See second to last input please.

Note: I was using http://try.mongodb.org/

```
> person = {fullname : "Derek Litz"}
{      "fullname" : "Derek Litz"      }
> db.people.save(person)
"ok"
> db.people.find()
     [        {   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "4df3b39ccc93747e68039f08"   },   "fullname" : "Derek Litz"   }     ]
> db.people.find({fullname : 'Derek Litz'})
     [        {   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "4df3b39ccc93747e68039f08"   },   "fullname" : "Derek Litz"   }     ]
> db.people.find({fullname : /^D.*/})
     [             ]
> db.people.find({fullname : {$regex : '^D.*'}})
     [        {   "_id" : {   "$oid" : "4df3b39ccc93747e68039f08"   },   "fullname" : "Derek Litz"   }     ]
>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think that's just a bug in `try.mongodb.org`. These work for me in my local `mongo` shell:

```
db.people.find({first_name: {$regex: /e/}})
db.people.find({first_name: /e/})
```

And the [documentation says this](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Advanced+Queries#AdvancedQueries-RegularExpressions):

> You may use regexes in database query expressions:
>
> `db.customers.find( { name : /acme.*corp/i } );`
>      `db.customers.find( { name : { $regex : 'acme.*corp', $options: 'i' } } );`
>   [...]
>      `db.customers.find( { name : { $regex : /acme.*corp/i, $nin : ['acmeblahcorp'] } } );`

So both string and RegExp literal versions are supported.

Answer (score 2):

It seems, that http://try.mongodb.org/ just doesn't support regular expressions for some reason. Real console is ok.

Comment: try.mongo.org supports regular expressions in string literals but doesn't seem to understand RegExp literals. So it does support them but its syntax doesn't completely line up with the documentation, the real mongo shell, or the real full blown mongo query interface.

Comment: @muistooshort - so what syntax should you use in the try.mongo?

Comment: @UpTheCreek: I'm not certain but maybe `new RegExp(...)` would work.